# GMap PanTo on GPS App

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

i'm building a simple GPS Application where i need to update the marker/my position on the map. That's the code i'm using:

```
$('#map').live('pagecreate', function(){
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '0,0', 'zoom': 10, 'callback': function(map) {
        var self = this;
        self.watchPosition(function(position, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                if (!self.get('markers').client) {
                    self.addMarker({'id': 'client', 'position': latlng, 'bounds': true});
                } else {
                    self.get('markers').client.setPosition(latlng);
                    map.panTo(latlng);
                }
            }
        });
    }});
});
```

I didn't tested if the marker is moving yet, but my question is why the "panTo" function pans to the marker with maximum zoom? I just need it to follow the marker/my position at the actual zoom. How can that be made?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

SetCenter of the map to match the marker..

```
var latLng = marker.getPosition();  
map.setCenter(latLng);
```